# Loading data in Colabs Transfer learning / fine-tuning

Tags: python

I want to make an image classifier and saw Colabs "transfer learning for smaller data set. I was trying to run notebook scripts to see their native results using 101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz.. running the code in notebook to get the data returns error... This is on PC window 10
https://colab.research.google.com/github/kylemath/ml4a-guides/blob/master/notebooks/transfer-learning.ipynb#scrollTo=XklKIrnaZb3f
Note book code is...

!echo "Downloading 101_Object_Categories for image notebooks"
!curl -L -o 101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz --progress-bar http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz
!tar -xzf 101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz
!rm 101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz
!lsnter code here

Result output

Downloading 101_Object_Categories for image notebooks
#-#O=#  #
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
drive  sample_data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i’m trying to load the data from their file and the code as written in their notebook does not work. Or load properly. Do I have to decompress or unzip the data file as an extra step to get to the data somehow?

Comment: I got it to work properly after unzipping all the data and putting the images on my Google Drive.